# New SugarCRM Error {"content":" after fresh install

Tags: sugarcrm

I've installed SugarCRM Community Version 6.5.14 (Build 1055) for the first time. I am not a newbie, but definitely a newbie to this script. After installing with the sample data, I get the following error when viewing any pages.

```
An error has occurred:
{"content":"
```

I'm open to suggestions as I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Find any error message in file sugarCRM.log

Answer (score 1):

Have you give permissions to all the modules